# Scikit learn LogisticRegression log loss increases when adding features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am performing a Multinomial Logistic Regression on variables in the [NHTS 2017](https://nhts.ornl.gov/) dataset.  According to the docs, `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` uses cross-entropy loss (log loss) as the loss function to optimize the model.  However, as I add new features and fit the model, the loss does not seem to be monotone decreasing.  Specifically, if I fit household driver count to vehicle ownership, (driver count is the single most predictive variable for vehicle ownership), I get less loss than if I indiscriminately fit all of the variables.

Possibly this is due to `sklearn.metrics.log_loss` doing something different than the actual loss function for `LogisticRegression`.  Possibly the problem has become so non-convex that it finds a crappy solution.  Can anybody hep explain why my loss would *increase* as I add features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons but my guess is the following:

- `penalty` - by default logistic regression is trained with a l2
  penalty to prevent overfitting. In this case, the loss function is cross entropy loss plus the l2 norm of weights. As a result, more features will not necessarily guarantee that the cross entropy itself decreases.

Btw, it seems like your goal is to get the highest score (lowest loss) on a training set. I am not gonna dispute that but maybe look into test/validation sets.

Comment: AH!  It's set to One vs Rest, not Multinomial, which uses cross entropy.  Thanks for the lead.  :)